# Unable to append newrow in csv file in pandas loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

```
def getOHLC_df(df):
    grouped = df.groupby('symbol')
    df_final = pd.DataFrame()
    global csv_data
    for name, group in grouped:
        group = group.sort_values('timestamp')
        timestamp = group['timestamp'].iloc[0]
        symbol = name
        open = group['ltp'].iloc[0]
        close = group['ltp'].iloc[-1]
        high = group['ltp'].max()
        low = group['ltp'].min()
        data = {
            'timestamp': timestamp,
            'symbol': symbol,
            'open': open,
            'close': close,
            'high': high,
            'low': low,}

        df_final = df_final.append(data, ignore_index=True)
        df_final = df_final.reindex(['timestamp', 'symbol', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close'], axis=1)

        field_names = ['timestamp', 'symbol', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low']

        with open('C:/Users/choud/Documents/'+symbol+'.csv','a') as f_object:
            # Pass the file object and a list
            # of column names to DictWriter()
            # You will get a object of DictWriter
            dictwriter_object = csv.DictWriter(f_object, fieldnames=field_names)

            # Pass the dictionary as an argument to the Writerow()
            dictwriter_object.writerow(data)

            # Close the file object
            f_object.close()

    print(df_final)
```

I wanted to store in csv file for the single row from pandas dataframe. I have dataframe for 200 stocks for specific time let's say from 9:15 to 9:30 . Wanted to add particular row in respective stock csv file. I have 200 csv files for different stocks.

I am getting issue as
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Comment: Are you able to give an example call to the function that recreates the problem? i.e. use [edit] to add some more details to the question

Comment: Hey Martin , Issue was I defined open earlier and then using with open that was throwing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are defining `open` as `open = group['ltp'].iloc[0]` earlier in the code and then later on trying to do a `with open('C:/Users/choud/Documents/'+symbol+'.csv','a') as f_object:`

Effectively, you have redefined `open` and it can no longer be used to open a file.

Comment: Hey Mortz , yaah you pointed it right . When I created a seperate file used with open csv by calling it from it worked . But I didn’t understand why . But your answer clarified it . Thanks